# Add part_of_the_day from time column given (first shift, second shift, dead time)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to add shift names from time column in my dataset.

```
7:00:00 to 17:00:00 (same day) - First Shift
17:00:01 to 4:00:00 (next morning) - Second Shift
4:00:01 to 6:59:59 (same morning) - Dead Time
```

I followed some given solutions form stack overflow but in vain.
Glimpse of the dataset

```
    Date    Time    
    2022-04-13  16:57:00        
    2022-09-07  10:46:00
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':range(1, 25)})

b = [4,7,17,24]
l = ['Dead Time', 'First Shift','Second Shift']
df['Shifts'] = pd.cut(df['Time'], bins=b, labels=l, include_lowest=True)
```

Comment: added an answer, does it help?

Comment: Thank you so much this helped!
(Had to combine date and time column together for pd.datetime)

Comment: Got NaN for all the times from 00:00:00 to 01:00:00 (12 am - 1 am)

Changed b -> b=[-1, 3, 6, 16, 24]

Comment: did you use the second solution? where a minute is removed? I updated the solution to make it -1 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# define bins
b=[-1, 3, 6, 16, 24]

# define labels
l = ['Second Shift','Dead Time', 'First Shift','Second Shift']

# capture the hour from the Time and then label using pd.cut
df['shift']=pd.cut( pd.to_datetime (df['Time']).dt.hour,
      bins=b,
      labels=l,
      ordered=False)
df
```

```
Date    Time    shift
0   2022-04-13  01:57:00    Second Shift
1   2022-09-07  02:46:00    Second Shift
2   2022-04-13  04:57:00    Dead Time
3   2022-04-13  05:57:00    Dead Time
4   2022-04-13  07:57:00    First Shift
5   2022-04-13  10:57:00    First Shift
6   2022-04-13  12:57:00    First Shift
7   2022-04-13  17:57:00    Second Shift
8   2022-04-13  19:57:00    Second Shift
9   2022-04-13  22:57:00    Second Shift
```

in case if you shift is ending at the top of the hour at 00 minutes, shift time by 1 minute and above bins will work, without the need of looking into minutes

```
df['shift']=pd.cut( (pd.to_datetime (df['Time'])  + pd.offsets.Minute(-1)) .dt.hour,
      bins=b,
      labels=l,
      ordered=False)
df
```